# Why is there overflow for my H.264 video even though its dimensions are smaller than the browser window?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

- I have a 1280x720 video (*AAC, H.264* in case it's important)
- My browser window is 1440x764
- I have the following CSS:

```
#original-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

- and the following HTML

```
<body>
  <video id="original-video" width="1280" height="720" playsinline>
    <source src="/db/original.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
<body>
```

And yet when the video is rendered on the page, there is a vertical and horizontal overflow. Which makes no sense as the width and the height of the video is supposedly smaller than the width and the height of the window.

How can I fix this and have the video fit inside the window ?

**EDIT:** I think it's because of the hight resolution of the video. Even though it "says" it's 1280x720, the rendered dimensions are actually larger. But I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the CSS into something like:

```
#original-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 77.2223%;
}
```

resizes the video proportionally to fit my 1440x764 window.

So it was indeed due to the higher resolution of the video.

But I don't know if this is the proper way to fix this so I'm tentatively adding this as an answer while I wait for someone more experienced to confirm or suggest a more appropriate solution.

Comment: I was thinking the same. To have a width in % rather than PX.